# Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed in read file function

Tags: r, average

Can someone help me out with this one? I'm getting this error: `Error in if (numList[i]%%2 != 0) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. I know it means that some of my data is NA but I have no clue how to solve this.

What I'm trying to do is read three files, calculate the average of all odd numbers and save these values to 'average.txt' file.

My code: 
Function to calc the average:

```
calcAvg <- function(numList) {
  oddList <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(numList)) {
    if(numList[i] %% 2 != 0) {
      oddList = c(oddList, numList[i])
    }
  }
  avg <- mean(oddList)
  return(format(round(avg,2 ), nsmall =2))
}
```

And the function where error occurs:

```
writeToFile <- function() {
  file.create("average.txt", showWarnings = TRUE)
  myFile <- file("average.txt", open="w")
  f = file.path(getwd(), c("data1.txt", "data2.txt", "data3.txt"))
  d <- lapply(f, readFile)
  str(d)
  allNumAvg = calcAvg(as.numeric(unlist(d))) < --- error points on this line after traceback
  data1 = calcAvg(as.numeric(unlist(readFile("data1.txt"))))
  data2 = calcAvg(readFile("data2.txt"))
  data3 = calcAvg(readFile("data3.txt"))
  write(allNumAvg, myFile, append=TRUE)
  write((data1), myFile, sep = "\n")
  write((data2), myFile, sep = "\n")
  write(data3, myFile)
  close(myFile)
}
```

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to simplify your function a little bit. I don't know what your data looks like exactly, but for a vector of numbers to calculate the mean of all odd numbers, you dont need a for loop. Here is an example:

```
test <- 1:10

mean(test[test %% 2 != 0]) #calculates the mean of all odd numbers in the vector
[1] 5
```

If you have `NA`s in your data, just add `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
test[1] <- NA
mean(test[test %% 2 != 0])    #wont work
[1] NA
mean(test[test %% 2 != 0], na.rm=TRUE)      #works
[1] 6
```